# Differentiation of $x!$, where $x\in \mathbb{N}+\{0\}$

Tags: calculus

Calculation of $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}(x!) = $, where $x\in \mathbb{N}+\{0\}$

My Try:: We Know that $x! = (x)\cdot (x-1)\cdot(x-2)...........(3)\cdot(2)\cdot(1)$

Now Taking $\bf{\ln}$ on both side

$\bf{\ln(x!)} = \ln (x)+\ln(x-1)+\ln(x-2)+................+\ln(3)+\ln(2)+\ln(1)$

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}(\ln (x!)) = \frac{d}{dx}\left\{\ln (x)+\ln(x-1)+\ln(x-2)+................+\ln(3)+\ln(2)+\ln(1)\right\}$

Now I Did not understand How can I solve Given Question,

Help Required

Thanks

Comment: You can not differentiate the discrete function. Take a look at the gamma function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, consider the function

$$ f(x)= \ln(\Gamma(x+1)) \implies f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\ln(\Gamma(x+1)) = \frac{\Gamma'(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+1)}=\psi(x+1), $$

which is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).